# How to find the cursor to be closed with this message W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close() in Android

Tags: android, cursor, resolver

I have several cursors opened but how to find which one to be close? shall I include a cursor.close() in the databasehelper before returning the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You should not close the Cursor before returning it, as you will not be able to use it then.

AFAIK any native Android functions that use a Cursor close it automatically for you